# Why is my notification icon not displayed properly in Oreo?

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

We have notifications in our app since a long time, which work fine. I have a small, multicoloured .png-icon we use for them, that have worked fine in the past.

**In Oreo, the icon is not displayed properly, it is just a grey square.** Looking at the drawer on the device, it seems that the system, gmail etc. all now have single-colour icons, so i suspect that it has something to do with that.

However, i can't find any documentation, design guidelines or anything that confirm this, so i am surrendering to a question here...

How can i make my icon display as normal in Oreo? What am i missing?

This is how i create the icon, from what i can see in documentation it should work, and it works pre-Oreo:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

builder.setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Title").setWhen(when)
.setContentText(message).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
.setSmallIcon("icon.png").setContentIntent(contentIntent);

getNotificationManager(context).notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Comment: Just the alpha channel of the icon is used (and not only since Oreo). So make sure your icon has a meaningful alpha channel.

Comment: what do u mean by alpha channel ?? @Henry

Comment: @D_K this is the channel that controls the transparency of the icon.

Answer (score 0):

[refer this site](https://medium.com/@raziaranisandhu/push-notification-on-oreo-6129289a5a8c)
In this site you may see this

> You can see that I have set different small icons. **Small icon need to
> be vector icon on Lollipop and upper Android versions. Otherwise it
> will show colored dot only as small icon.**

If you have png,jpeg,jpg image file then convert it to svg and import this svg file into android studio using "Vector Asset" option and you are ready to go!!